# конвертация flash в html 5

Tags: php, flash, curl, google-api

делаю по данной статье [ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/company/targetix/blog/265739/)

```
const GOOGLE_API_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCC_WIu0oVvLtQGzv4-g7oaWNoc-u8JpEI";

header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8', true);
if($_FILES['f']['tmp_name']){
    $content =  file_get_contents($_FILES['f']['tmp_name']);
    print_r($content);
    $content = str_replace('+','-',base64_encode($content));
    $content = str_replace('/','_',$content);
}
else{
    return false;
}

$request_data = array(
    'apiVersion' => 'v1',
    'method ' => 'swiffy.convertToHtml',
    'params' => array(
        'client' => 'Swiffy Flash Extension',
        'input'  => $content
    )
);
$json = json_encode($request_data);
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, GOOGLE_API_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print_r(curl_error($ch));
}
print_r($response);
```

мне постоянно возвращает такой ответ`{"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse Error","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"parseError","message":"Parse Error"}]}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
'method ' => 'swiffy.convertToHtml',
```

был лишний пробел, из-за которого все валилось,
нужно: 
`'method' => 'swiffy.convertToHtml',`